# How to change the label at the time of radio button selection is changed using asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

here is my following stuff in asp.net

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RbList" runat="server" 
    onselectedindexchanged="RbList_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Male" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Female" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>


    </asp:RadioButtonList>
<asp:Label ID="lbltest" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

and here is my `RBList_SelectedIndexChanged` event.

```
int i = RbList.SelectedIndex;
    if (i == 1)
    {
        lbltest.Text = "You have click on male";
    }
    if (i == 2)
    {lbltest.Text = "You have click on female";}
```

Now, I want when item 1 is selected the text lable must be according to the selected item of radiobutton list.

How could be this is possible?

Regards.

Comment: add AutoPostback="True" to your RbList, or do it in javascript

Comment: The best way for do this function in javascript or jQuery.

Comment: please use javaScript for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Set Autopostback="true" on RbList
2. change your code to the following:

   > ```
   > int i = RbList.SelectedIndex;
   > if (i == 0)
   >    {
   > lbltest.Text = "You have click on male";
   >     }
   > else if (i == 1)
   > { lbltest.Text = "You have click on female"; }
   > ```

Comment: the SelectedIndex is 0 & 1 not 1 & 2